# ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer Zoom + LocateButton

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Have few questions about DynamicMap options.

1.Can i implement LocateButton?

2.Can i set the starting Zoom on the map?

This is my Code that is use only with LocateButton but wont work with him, if LocateButton is taken off the map work fine.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Create Map and add a dynamic layer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/esri/css/esri.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  html, body, #mapDiv{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

  #search {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 20px;
  left: 84px;
}

#LocateButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 50;
}
</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>
<script>
  var map;

  require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
    "esri/dijit/LocateButton",
    "esri/layers/ImageParameters"
  ], function (
    Map, LocateButton, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, ImageParameters) {

    map = new Map("mapDiv", {
      sliderOrientation : "horizontal",
    });

    geoLocate = new LocateButton({
    map: map
    }, "LocateButton");
    geoLocate.startup();


    var imageParameters = new ImageParameters();
    imageParameters.format = "jpeg"; //set the image type to PNG24, note default is PNG8.

    //Takes a URL to a non cached map service.
    var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://gis.katastar.gov.mk/arcgis/rest/services/Raster/Ortofoto_MK_color/MapServer", {
      //"opacity" : 0.5,
      "imageParameters" : imageParameters,
    });

    map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer);
  });


  require([
   "esri/dijit/Search",
   "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
   "esri/InfoTemplate",
   "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function (Search, FeatureLayer,InfoTemplate) {




        var search = new Search({
        enableButtonMode: true, //this enables the search widget to display as a single button
        enableLabel: false,
        enableInfoWindow: true,
        showInfoWindowOnSelect: false,
        map: map
     }, "search");



     //var sources = search.get("sources");
    var sources = [];
     //Push the sources used to search, by default the ArcGIS Online World geocoder is included. In addition there is a feature layer of US congressional districts. The districts search is set up to find the "DISTRICTID". Also, a feature layer of senator information is set up to find based on the senator name. 



     sources.push({
        featureLayer: new FeatureLayer("http://62.162.76.153/arcgis/rest/services/Kiosci_MKD/MapServer/0"),
        searchFields: ["HR_TITLE"],
        displayField: "HR_TITLE",
        exactMatch: false,
        outFields: ["HR_TITLE", "OBJECTID", "HR_DESCRIPTION"],
        name: "Znamenitosti",
        placeholder: "Enter Value",
        maxResults: 50,
        maxSuggestions: 10,

        //Create an InfoTemplate and include three fields
        infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate("Skopje City", "Point Name: ${HR_TITLE}</br>Description: ${HR_DESCRIPTION}"),
        enableSuggestions: true,
        minCharacters: 0
     });



     sources.push({
        featureLayer: new FeatureLayer("MY SERVICE"),
        searchFields: ["HR_TITLE"],
        displayField: "HR_TITLE",
        exactMatch: false,
        name: "Smestuvanje",
        outFields: ["*"],
        placeholder: "Enter Value",
        maxResults: 50,
        maxSuggestions: 20,

        //Create an InfoTemplate

   //Set the sources above to the search widget
     search.set("sources", sources);

     search.startup();



});



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the thread below, its necessary to declare a default [geometryService](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html) in your application in order for the LocateButton widget to reproject the lat/long locations returned by HTML5 into the coordinates used by your own basemap.

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/83347#comment-391644

API reference esriConfig.geometryService
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.config-amd.html

also, since the map service you're displaying has already been cached (as evidenced by `Single Fused Map Cache: true` in the service metadata), it would be more appropriate to display it in your application using an [ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/arcgistiledmapservicelayer-amd.html).

you can set the starting zoom for maps in any projection, but since your own basemap does not use the common Web Mercator coordinate system, you'll have to pass an esri/geometry/[Point](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/point-amd.html) object with valid XY coordinates for your own projection in the Map constructor.

Map Constructor - center
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1

```
The location where the map should be centered. 
Enter the location as an array containing longitude and latitude 
(for example, [-98, 40]) or as an esri.geometry.Point.
```